# How can I get the longitude and latitude of a specific place using Google's GeoCoder Java Client?

Tags: java, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get the longitude and latitude of a specific address.

This is the result of the GeoCoded response with the address I am using as a parameter.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "plus_code": {
            "compound_code": "CWC8+W5 Mountain View, California, United States",
            "global_code": "849VCWC8+W5"
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I need to specifically get the longitude and latitude of the place.I am following the code [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java)

I need the specific JSON field so that I can use it in my Java Code

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

The code in the github page shows that:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("AIza...").build();
GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
    "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043").await();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(results[0].addressComponents));
```

The 4th line only accesses the "addressComponents" of the JSON String. To get the latitudes, I just had to use the corresponding field names and replace the 4th line of the code above with:

```
System.out.println(gson.toJson(results[0].geometry.location.lat));
```